# Download a file from the web in C++ without using non-standard libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, url

When I say non-standard libraries, I am referring to things like Boost, libCurl and anything else that may be able to do this far easier than standard C++ can. The reason for this is that I am writing an application as a piece of coursework (the class is dedicated to C++) and I am required to use only standard libraries and functions.

I am looking to download a RSS file, using a URL that the user will supply (I'm building a rudimentary RSS client), and the biggest problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure how to get the file down. Once I get past that bit, parsing it for the xml tags and displaying the content will be relatively straightforward. I've been looking around and I've only found solutions that say to use non-standard libraries, usually libCurl. If someome could just give me a quick heads up about what I should be looking at for this, then I'd be grateful.

Also, if you think you're helping me cheat, you're not. The assignment is to build an application of our choice and we're being graded on our use of the various feature of the language (it must contain so many classes, use these variables types, etc).

Comment: What's the actual question? Do you want someone to write you an app to do this? Have you written your own and are experiencing problems with it?

Comment: @jon hanson I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, and I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: "Once I get past that bit, parsing it for the xml tags and displaying the content will be relatively straightforward." - good luck with that.

Comment: Note the use of the word _relatively_ ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for a quick but excellent introduction to sockets. If you cannot use any non-standard libraries, your only option is to manually connect on port 80 and make the request yourself.

Assuming even a beginner-level knowledge of C++, that should be all you need.

Answer (score 9):

First off, it can't be done using only standard C++. There is no network interface in either standard C++ or standard C.

If you're required to take a "do-it-yourself" approach, then probably the intention is that you would use your platform's sockets API. In the case of linux, this is part of the POSIX standard, not C++, and is available from `<sys/socket.h>`.

The basic procedure is: parse the URL; look up the IP address of the domain; create a socket; connect the socket; write an HTTP request to the socket; read the HTTP response back from the socket; clean up.

Obviously, an HTTP library is far more convenient, especially since an HTTP download can get more complicated than what I describe above (for example, if the server responds with a redirect). Pretty much all linux distributions will provide `libcurl`, and/or the `curl` and `wget` programs.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there is no network interface in the standard C++ (or C) library.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a program to make a socket connection is relatively trivial.

> http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Now that you have a socket open to an HTTP server you need to understand how to ask for a document and how to decode the reply:

> http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

Basically you need to send:

```
GET<SP><URL><SP>HTTP/1.1<CRLF>

Where:
  SP:    Single Space
  CRLF:  \r\n
  URL:   The Full URL of the page including the server name.
```

What you get back will be

> http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6

```
HTTP/1.1<SP>200<SP>OK<CRLF>
(<Header><CRLF>)*
<CRLF>
<Document>
```

The above means:

- The first line is the response line that should contain 200 OK.

  - If it does not then there is some kind of error and you should just give up.
- This is followed by 0 or more header lines

  - Just ignore these lines
- There will be 1 empty line to mark the end of the headers.
- Then the document will be on the stream.

Comment: "If it does not then there is some kind of error and you should just give up." - well, there's 3xx. With a user-supplied URL, most likely it will turn out to be necessary to follow redirects.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it without using libcurl you can always open a tcp socket and then send:

```
GET /myurl
```

(http 1.0 or preferably use [http 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP_1.1_Upgrade_header_field))

Basically you're writing a very simple http protocol client implementation.

Comment: libcurl definitely  falls under the "standard library" category.

Comment: @hassan I agree, but the question specifically asked for "not using libcurl" which leaves little choice

Comment: indeed, just saw that. Strange that any university lecturer would lead his class to assume that libcurl is considered non-standard. Anyhow the next best answer for the OP is to "read" the curl source code.

Comment: The libcurl source code isn't particularly clear for just simple http requests and I suspect the "learning outcome" for this assignment is something like "gain an insight into the http protocol" or some such. RFC2616 or wikipedia seems better suited to that than reading real implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can download source code for *wget* standard utility

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not allowed to use non-standard libraries, you could write your own primitive wrapper class for the linux "curl" command (I'm assuming you are using linux).  Curl is a very powerful command, and it can probably do what you need it to.